# click link using getelementsbyclassname vba 7 using access 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access, hyperlink, click

I have a connection to an internet explorer webpage but i cannot seem to "click" a specific link using vba7 in access. I've tried loads of options like getelementsbyclassname. Here's the source code from the webpage:

```
<tr> 
 <td valign=bottom class="formbutton" align=center colspan=2>
  <A href="default.asp" LANGUAGE=javascript onclick="return webDialogBox_wfsubmit('BUTTON',12293,0);">view</A>
 </td>
</tr>
```

As you can see it has no name nor a usable hyperlink and the purpose of this link is to submit the filled-out form and give it a unique number on a new web page.
Can you please help me in VBA 7 for Access 2007 to come up with a vba code that works?
Many thanks!

Comment: souce code is <tr>
<td valign=bottom  class="formbutton"  align=center colspan=2><A href="default.asp" LANGUAGE=javascript onclick="return WebDialogBox_wfsubmit('BUTTON',12293,0);">view</A></td></tr>

Comment: It's solved! All it needed was a 5 sec pause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work assuming you have a pointer to the InternetExplorer object already.

```
Public Sub ClickElement()
    'Assuming you already have an IE object
    Dim Elements As Object
    Dim Element As Object

    'get all 'A' tags, which the hyperlink is part of
    Set Elements = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

    For Each Element In Elements
        'I believe the element you want to click appears as 'View' on screen
        If Element.InnerText = "View" Then
            'Usually a good idea to give the element focus and
            'possibly fire the OnClick event, but sometimes not needed
            Element.Focus
            Element.Click
            Element.FireEvent ("OnClick")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ryan Wildry Ty for your fast answer, but unfortunately nothing happens. Not even an error. Its like it doesnt see the hyperlink. When I click with the mouse everything works just fine. What info would you need to help me? Grz sebastiaan

Comment: You'll need to step through the code and review which elements are in the Elements Collection. Double check the InnerText property is showing 'View'

Comment: I don now how to do that. Could you tell me how (im a self educated person but not a programmer)? Or is there a tutorial i could use?